# event attach with on is not unbinding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading `.html` file using jquery `load()` function. The html file which i am loading

contains some script, in that script there is `keydown event` binded with the document,

like :          `$(document).on("keydown", handler);`. Now in the callback of `load()` i am

trying to unbind `keydown event`, `$(document).off("keydown");` but the event was not unbind.

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: yes and i already mentioned in my question @Florent

Comment: This is practically impossible to answer without seeing your code. Please post both the part of the loaded HTML page that binds the event, and the callback that attempts to unbind it.

Comment: According to the jQuery documentation, what you are describing is entirely correct and should work.  The problem is likely somewhere else.  Show your code, as @Utkanos said.

Comment: Well, according to your comments, it seems that you did the right things. Can you edit your question to add more information such as pieces of code? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using `bind` and `trigger` to attach and fire events instead of `on`.

Comment: Should be equivalent. The jQuery documentation says `on` is the preferred method.  http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: My bad, I didn't know it. I'm totally old school.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $(document).unbind("keydown");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try unbind the event like this:

```
$('#foo').unbind();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
$(document).off("keydown", "*");
```